# Keyboard Callback Telegram API

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Знаю что inlineKeyboard могут возвращать callback_data при нажатии на них.

```
$CancelView = Array("text" => "Отменить просмотр", "callback_data" => "cancel_view");
$CheckView = Array("text" => "Проверить просмотр", "callback_data" => "check_view");
$inline_keyboard = [[$CancelPay],[$CheckView]];
$keyboard = Array("inline_keyboard" => $inline_keyboard);
$replyMarkup = json_encode($keyboard)
```

Но могут ли возвращать callback_data или что-либо наподобии этого обычные Keyboards ?

```
$location = Array("text" => "Отправить мое местоположение", "request_location" => true); 
$cancel = Array("text" => "НУЖЕН КАЛБЭК", "callback_data" => "cancel_view");
$Keyboards = [[$location, $cancel]];
$KeyboardSet = Array("keyboard" => $Keyboards, "resize_keyboard" => true, "one_time_keyboard" => true);
$replyMarkup = json_encode($KeyboardSet);
```

При попытке нажатия на кнопку "НУЖЕН КАЛБЭК", собственно эта фраза просто отправляется в чат и никакой callback не передается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, никаких коллбэков обычная клавиатура не передаёт, а передаёт непосредственно текст в чат. В этом и заключается **ключевое различие** между [KeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton) и [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton), посмотрите на список полей этих двух типов - у **KeyboardButton** их только три:

1. **text** - текст кнопки, передающийся в чат;
2. **request_contact** - запрашивать/не запрашивать номер телефона пользователя;
3. **request_location** - запрашивать/не запрашивать местоположение пользователя;

В то же время, запрос контакта и местоположения доступен только с помощью обычной клавиатуры. Соответственно, каждый из этих типов применим для своего специфичного функционала.

Comment: А можно ли одновременно использовать KeyboardButton и InlineKeyboardButton ?

Comment: @LorDo - Конечно можно, встроенная клавиатура отображается у сообщений, а обычная внизу чата, вместо поля ввода текста